# Playing a video in Unity in 360 degree view

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I was following this https://vimeo.com/120757981 to make a 360 video.

The issue I am facing as as follows:

1. Obj file imported from Blender in Unity
2. Attaching a video to it
3. Changing shader settings
4. Attaching the play script
5. Running the app

Result:
Everything thing was black and video didn't get played

Help Required:
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You got Unity Pro?

Comment: Hi @Pawel: Yes I have..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check the direction of the normals in the blender model, if you create a sphere you need to invert the normals so when you place the camera  inside the sphere you could see the video. Then import the model from blender to unity, asign a custom material to the sphere, import the video too, create the Play Video script,and done!!.
The PlayVideo script should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @ Jasiel. How shall I import the normals?

Comment: Worked out for me. Thanks much Jasiel!